# How to hide row after changing status in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm now trying to hide clicked row after changing status in angularjs. Here is my coding and please let me know how to do it?

```
table.table
    tr(data-ng-repeat="application in job.applications", ng-hide="application.hideApplication")
        td.status
            div.bold #{getMessage('Change Status:')}
            div.normal
                a(ng-class="app_status === 'shortlist' ? 'admin_edit_bold' : 'admin_edit_normal'", ng-click="changeApplicationStatus(application.id, 'shortlist', application)") #{getMessage('Shortlist')}
        td.rating
            div(ng-init='rating = application.app_rating')
            .star-rating(star-rating='', rating-value='rating', data-max='5', on-rating-selected='rateFunction(application.id, rating)')
```

Here is controllerjs.

```
$scope.changeApplicationStatus = function (appId, app_status, application) {
    return jobsService.changeApplicationStatus(appId, app_status).then(
        function () {
            application.hideApplication = false;
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this attribute on whichever element you're wanting to show/hide

```
ng-hide="application.hideApplication"
```

**Edit subsequent to comment:**

That attribute wouldn't work on the same element as the ng-repeat, I don't think the application variable would be in scope...

Instead, you could change your repeat to:

```
application in job.applications | filter: { hideApplication : false }
```

Comment: sorry, i've forget to put `ng-hide="application.hideApplication"` in tr. it's not working even I've added.

Comment: @ppshein updated with a filter in your repeat statement, let me know if that meets your needs.